# Get the data value of anchor tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<ul>
    <li><a id="tab1" data-index="0" name="tab" href="#">abc</a></li>
    <li><a id="tab2" data-index="1" name="tab" href="#">def</a></li>
    <li><a id="tab3" data-index="2" name="tab" href="#">ijk</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is my Question 
 If I click on any Anchor tag, I want to get the `[data-index]` value of selected item. 
and am not supposed to use  Id Selector or Class selector
This is what I tried using jQuery but it's not working

```
$("a[name=tab]").on("click", function () { 
    var a = $(this).getAttribute("data-index"); 
    alert(a); 
});
```

Thank u

Comment: `$(this).data('index')`

Answer (score 11):

use `.attr()` in jquery

```
 $("a[name=tabs]").on("click", function () { 
            var a = $(this).attr("data-index"); 
            alert(a); 
        });
```

or use `.data()` in jquery

```
 $("a[name=tabs]").on("click", function () { 
            var a = $(this).data("index"); 
            alert(a); 
        });
```

[***Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/EqRLa/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use **[.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)**:

> Return the value at the named data store for the first element in the
>   jQuery collection, as set by data(name, value) or by an HTML5 data-*
>   attribute.

```
var a = $(this).data("index");
```

Also note that the `name` of your anchor is `tab` not `tabs`, so you need to use:

```
$("a[name=tab]").on("click", function () { 
    var a = $(this).data("index"); 
    alert(a); 
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Gex6U/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$("a[name=tabs]").on("click", function () { 
    var a = $(this).data('index'); 
    alert(a); 
});
```

I would definately have a look at this [link](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) because it shows the change in HTML 5 and how we can use jQuery to effectively get information from HTML 5 data attributes.

Answer (score 0):

use `.data()`:

```
$(this).data('index')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

> ```
> $(this).attributes['data-index'].value;
> ```